# Tracing object's path

Tags: animation

I am working on a scientific visualization.

Scene is like there is a sphere and I want to mark down the path that it passes through.

Sphere follows a completely unknown path, so I can't draw it manually.
Glad to get help!!!

Comment: Add a . blend file or a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: enter link description here]

**Motion Paths**

From the [blender user manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/motion_paths.html)

Editor: 3D View, Properties editor
Mode:   Object Mode
Panel:  Properties editor ‣ Object ‣ Motion Paths

The Motion Paths tool allows you to visualize the motion of points as paths over a series of frames. These points can be object origins and bone joints.
**Motion Paths**

To create or remove motion paths, it is necessary to first select the bones. Then:

- To show the paths (or update them, if needed), click on the Calculate Path button.
- To hide the paths, click on the Clear Paths button.

[image]

These are display only, to get them as actual object you'd need to convert them using a script, there's one in this [blender artists thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/convert-object-motion-path-to-curve/679316)

Unfortunately this won't work in blender 2.81, but with a slight modification it does, here's the updated version:

```
## path from -calculated- motion path

import bpy
ob = bpy.context.object
mp = ob.motion_path

if mp:
    path = bpy.data.curves.new('path','CURVE')
    curve = bpy.data.objects.new('Curve',path)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(curve)
    path.dimensions = '3D'
    spline = path.splines.new('BEZIER')
    spline.bezier_points.add(len(mp.points)-1)

    for i,o in enumerate(spline.bezier_points):
        o.co = mp.points[i].co
        o.handle_right_type = 'AUTO'
        o.handle_left_type = 'AUTO'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is really very helpful.